# Cannot load SVG's in Matter.js

Tags: javascript, svg, matter.js

I keep getting an error when trying to load an SVG in Matter-JS. I am basically copying and pasting code from the example to try and get this to work. I have installed poly-decomp and am using webpack and npm. The error is:

"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'numberOfItems')"

Here is the snippet of code where I am trying to load an SVG:

```
    // module aliases
const Engine = Matter.Engine,
    Common = Matter.Common,
    Composite = Matter.Composite,
    Vertices = Matter.Vertices,
    Svg = Matter.Svg,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies;

// provide concave decomposition support library
Common.setDecomp(require('poly-decomp'));
const engine = Engine.create(),
    world = engine.world;

    if (typeof fetch !== 'undefined') {
        var select = function(root, selector) {
            return Array.prototype.slice.call(root.querySelectorAll(selector));
        };

        var loadSvg = function(url) {
            return fetch(url)
                .then(function(response) { return response.text(); })
                .then(function(raw) { return (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(raw, 'image/svg+xml'); });
        };

        ([
            './puzzle.svg'
        ]).forEach(function(path, i) { 
            loadSvg(path).then(function(root) {
                // var color = Common.choose(['#f19648', '#f5d259', '#f55a3c', '#063e7b', '#ececd1']);

                var vertexSets = select(root, 'path')
                    .map(function(path) { return Vertices.scale(Svg.pathToVertices(path, 30), 0.4, 0.4); });

                Composite.add(world, Bodies.fromVertices(0,i * -100, vertexSets, {
                    isStatic: true
                }, true));
            });
        });

        loadSvg('./svg/svg.svg').then(function(root) {
            // var color = Common.choose(['#f19648', '#f5d259', '#f55a3c', '#063e7b', '#ececd1']);
            
            var vertexSets = select(root, 'path')
                .map(function(path) { return Svg.pathToVertices(path, 30); });

            Composite.add(world, Bodies.fromVertices(400, 80, vertexSets, {
                isStatic: true
            }, true));
        });
    } else {
        Common.warn('Fetch is not available. Could not load SVG.');
    }
```